# Чтение txt документа

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня такой вопрос: можно ли прочитать содержимое .txt файла без использования php и iframe, чтобы содержимое .txt переходило в textarea?

Многие говорят, что это невозможно, но я знаю, что как-то можно это сделать. Может, вы, мудрецы, как-то сделаете?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если со своего домена, или с компьютера пользователя, то Ajax или HTML5/File API.

**С компьютера:**

```
// Где-то в верстке есть <input id="inputFile" type="file"/>
inputFile.onchange = function () {
  var file = inputFile.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader;

  reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    textarea.value = reader.result; // file content
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

---

**C сервера**

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', '/files/foo.txt', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      textarea.value = xhr.responseText; // file content
    }
  }
};

xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос: А что мне в html писать?

Comment: Наверно это покажется очень странным и глупым ответом, но то что сверху написано и нужно.

Comment: А вы не могли бы где то пример показать?

Comment: @Юра Спивак, ну нельзя ж быть таким беспомощным... [Держите пример][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/eoum8sgj/